# String literal, getting compiler to compute length for string_view constructor

Tags: c++, c++14

I am writing code for an ARM Cortex. Processor cycles are precious and I am trying to get the most work possible from my compiler. I have many calls to UART_WriteStr(), the majority of which use a string literal.

```cpp
main() {
   ...
   UART_WriteStr("Initialization complete");
   ...
}
```

Currently UART_WriteStr() looks something like this:

```cpp
void UART_WriteStr(boost::string_view data) {
    uint32_t timeout = UINT32_MAX;
    for (auto el: data) {
      //UART peripheral control logic
    }
}
```

(My ARM compiler can not handle C++17 or above, which is why I am using boost::string_view)

That is pretty nice, string_view takes the pointer and doesn't do any new allocation. But I can see in the assembly for the string_view constructor that it determines the length by iterating over the string looking for a null character. I find that annoying, the compiler knows the length and string_view has a constructor that takes a pointer and length. But how to use that constructor?

I could do this:

```cpp
int constexpr const_cstr_length(const char* str) {
    return *str ? 1 + const_cstr_length(str + 1) : 0;
}
boost::string_view constexpr CCstr(const char * msg) {
    return {msg, static_cast<size_t>(const_cstr_length(msg))};
}
main() {
...
   UART_WriteStr(CCstr("Initialization complete"));
...
}
```

But why should I have to decorate my strings with a special function? Why can't I overload UART_WriteStr() to get the behavior I want?

I tried this:

```cpp
static inline void UART_WriteStr(const char * data) {
    UART0_WriteFIFO(boost::string_view(data, const_cstr_length(data)));
}
```

But `data` is no longer constant and const_cstr_length() has devolved into an execution time loop again.

How can I overload UART_WriteStr() in such a way that I can create the boost::string_view from a compile time length? I was on the verge of declaring this impossible due to how C/C++ handle strings in function arguments, but the CCstr() gave me hope that I was wrong.

Comment: You're doing embedded programming, so is using templates OK here?

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes templates are okay. In fact, I have found them to very useful in forcing compile time optimizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative is with template:

```
template <std::size_t N>
void UART_WriteStr(const char (&data)[N]) {
    UART_WriteStr(boost::string_view(data, N - 1));
}
```

Note: string might contain `'\0'` inside it (as `""_bs` solution).

Comment: Both solutions (`operator ""_bs` and the template) produce the same assembly. But as in my case, where I have a fair bit of existing code, this makes for a much smoother fix.

Comment: @DanielR: You can also `constexpr` it, if `boost::string_view` is `constexpr`-capable.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that is in between decorating all your calls and adding an overloaded method would be to use a [user-defined literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) (available since c++11) to construct the `boost::string_view` directly at the call site. This has the advantage of providing clarity to the code, being easy to implement, and can be leveraged in other contexts without additional work (e.g. if there are calls to other methods).

### Sample Code

```cpp
#include <string>

size_t constexpr const_cstr_length(const char* str) {
    return *str ? 1 + const_cstr_length(str + 1) : 0;
}

// I don't have boost installed, so I just use the standard string_view here.
std::string_view operator ""_bs(const char *str) {
    return std::string_view{str, const_cstr_length(str)};
}

int main() {
    auto a = "abc"_bs;
    return 0;
}
```

**Update**:
Based on the comments by @RemyLebeau, the code can be much simpler.

```cpp
#include <string>

// I don't have boost installed, so I just use the standard string_view here.
std::string_view operator ""_bs(const char *str, size_t n) {
    return std::string_view{str, n};
}

int main() {
    auto a = "abc"_bs;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need `const_cstr_length()` at all, as a user-defined `operator""` for a **string** literal will receive the string's length (not counting the null terminator) directly from the compiler (read the page you linked to!), eg: `boost::string_view operator ""_bs(const char *str, size_t length) { return boost::string_view{str, length}; }` This is just like how the standard [`operator ""sv`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/operator%22%22sv) operator is defined for `std::string_view` in C++17 and later.

Comment: Nice. BTW when I looked up [operator""_sv](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/operator%22%22sv), I found that it takes 2 arguments a pointer and length, so it seems that const_cstr_length() is not needed.

Comment: @DanielR yup that is what I just said

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau, I should have caught that before posting.

Comment: Notice than the 2 codes are not equivalent (with `'\0'` inside the string): `"zero\0one"_bs` size is 4 for your version, and 8 for boost.